# Display website in careers PDF

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I consider my website to be one of the more interesting things on my resume, since it's an example of my work. Is there any reason it isn't displayed on the PDFs generated by Careers 2.0? I'd like to have it display near my email address and location (in the top right corner).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just added this.  It should go out either late this afternoon or early tomorrow.